# wlan0 wpa_supplicant and other

Tags: wpa

can't establish connection wia WIFI. Can't understant what I'm doing wrong:

there is connection properties from my windows PC
[image]

[image]

this is my /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
ap_scan=1
update_config=1
country=BY

network={
        proto=WPA2
        pairwise=CCMP
        priority=5
        ssid="TP-Link"
        psk="tzb2iXfU"
        scan_ssid=1
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

and this is output from

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf


Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=BY
wlan0: Trying to associate with c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6 (SSID='TP-Link' freq=2462 MHz)
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=BY
wlan0: Trying to associate with c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6 (SSID='TP-Link' freq=2462 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6 reason=0
wlan0: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="TP-Link" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=WRONG_KEY
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=BY
nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="TP-Link"
wlan0: Trying to associate with c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6 (SSID='TP-Link' freq=2462 MHz)
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=BY
wlan0: Trying to associate with c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6 (SSID='TP-Link' freq=2462 MHz)
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="TP-Link" auth_failures=2 duration=23 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6 reason=3 locally_generated=1
nl80211: Was expecting local disconnect but got another disconnect event first
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=BY
wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
wlan0: Failed to initiate AP scan
wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
wlan0: Failed to initiate AP scan
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="TP-Link"
wlan0: Trying to associate with c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6 (SSID='TP-Link' freq=2462 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:25:e9:79:7a:e6 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="TP-Link" auth_failures=3 duration=46 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=BY
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
```

I already try to do it with:

1. raspi-config - same result
2. wext driver - not work, operation not
   permitted
3. with encrypted password - same result
4. without proto,
   pairwise, priority, scan_ssid, key_mgmt - same (or similar?) result

OS version (I download image from 2019-02-16 from official web site):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
Release:        9.4
Codename:       stretch
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: raspberrypi
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: 5e5d951a965b4123b3fc825af94cb9eb
           Boot ID: 791f1953bd0d42d2ac85dcac04c80bad
  Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
            Kernel: Linux 4.14.79-v7+
      Architecture: arm
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -r
4.14.79-v7+
```

Comment: just a wild idea... The SSID "TP-Link" is rather generic. Could it be that there is another AP with that name around? If yes, please check the BSSID.

Comment: no, I live in private house

Comment: The massive clue is `ssid="TP-Link" auth_failures=3`. Get rid of these lines ```proto=WPA2
        pairwise=CCMP
        priority=5``` and these lines ```scan_ssid=1
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK``` you don't need them and if they're wrong it will break the connection. If "TP-Link" is a hidden SSID then un-hide it.

Comment: @Dougie, same thing

Comment: temporarily remove security from the AP and try connecting again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519795/wpa-supplicant-throws-reason-0-locally-generated-1

Comment: Are you running Raspbian 2018-11-13 or some other OS version or distro?

Comment: I disable security, and after I run wpa_supplicant nothing happen - just `Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant` and no more messages. However, pi device did not receive ip address from router, and `ping google.com` did nothting.

Comment: Please follow this [Check of WiFi connection](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93636/79866) until **Checkpoint3** and tell us what Checkpoint failed for you. Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo, I can't understand what you want. Checkpoint 1 and Checkpoint 2 it is rpi image installation. Already did it yesterday. I have no `/dev/sdb`, I have `/dev/mmcblk0`, and output for `sudo parted /dev/mmcblk0 print` same as in example. I can't understand, what this guy do, when he put wpa_supplicant config into boot partition, because nothing in my system reference this config file. And yes, I can't pass checkpoint 3, because no changes

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using **Raspbian** and you wrote:

> can't establish connection via WIFI. Can't understand what I'm doing wrong

so I assume your question is: **How can I setup a WiFi connection with Raspbian?**

In my comment I suggested to follow this [Check of WiFi connection](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93636/79866) until **Checkpoint3**. Checkpoint1 and 2 are to ensure to have a defined starting point. For example I have seen users starting from a mixed up setup or asking for help saying: "I have done everything as described" but doesn't told they have the RasPi running in a virtual environment (docker, VM, sophisticated network environment etc.).

You started **wpa_supplicant** on the command line that isn't needed and may miss some dependencies. And as noted in your comments you doesn't know the default way to headless setup a WiFi connection by creating  a `wpa_supplicant.conf` in the boot partition as documented at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi headless](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md). So it would be a good advise to follow the default setup until **Checkpoint3**.

As you wrote you can pass **Checkpoint3**. So you have a WiFi connection with internet access. This answers your question. Just use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging in to a school, university, or WPA-Enterprise wifi network try this (it has always worked for me):

```
network={
    ssid="wifi-network-trying-to-login"
    priority=1
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    eap=PEAP
    identity="your-user-name"
    password="your-password"
    phase1="peaplabel=0"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    }
```